# Mingw and make variables

Tags: c, makefile, mingw, gnu

I'm trying to compile an open source project on windows under mingw/msys.

The makefile contains (among others) this line

```
@${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f physfs.make
```

physfs.make contains (among others) these lines:

```
ifndef CC
  CC = gcc
endif
```

when I ran make I get the following error:

```
Creating obj/Debug/physfs
physfs.c
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [obj/Debug/physfs/physfs.o] Error 127
make: *** [physfs] Error 2
```

If I comment the ifndef / endif pair leaving CC = gcc intact, the build works. If instead of make I issue this command:

```
make -e CC=gcc
```

the build works as well. But when I run the following command in msys:

```
echo $CC
```

nothing is displayed.

I think there is something basic about how environment variables work in MSYS and make that I don't understand.

Could please some help me troubleshoot this issue, so I can understand *why* simple 'make' command complains and why the ifndef block doesn't function as I expect it to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CC` is one of several [implicit variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) automatically defined in a make session, so the line `ifndef CC` should *never* evaluate to true.

This explains why you see nothing on the command line for `echo $CC`. The MSYS environment has no concept of CC.

If you want to see the value of variables from within a make session, you can always use the [info](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) function:

```
$(info $(CC))
```

This will echo the value of the CC variable to the console at the point when that line in the makefile is evaluated.

Comment: Remark: the correct way to test if `$(CC)` has the default value would be `ifeq (default,$(origin CC))`.

Comment: @Jack Kelly: The make file is generated by premake utility http://industriousone.com/premake so I can't change what is being generated. On the premake website someone maintained that it's a bug in mingw-make, that CC by default equals to cc. The gnu man that e.James linked seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @zespri: The link that I posted agrees: CC is set to cc by default.

Comment: If I understood your last comment correctly, then this is what I meant too. Someone said (http://industriousone.com/post/how-do-i-echo-full-compile-command-modify-linkcmdcc-various) that mingw-make sets CC to a wrong value, and the link you gave suggests that setting CC to cc by default is how it was intended.

Comment: @zespri: Yes, we are saying the same thing. I had misunderstood your previous comment; I thought you meant that my link stated that the CC variable was *not* supposed to equal cc by default. I realize now that you meant the opposite `:)`